# CMD prompt C:>python --version doesn't show anaconda with python

Tags: python, anaconda

Why does Anaconda version not display when using command line

```
C:>python --version
```

?

All the guidance shows that when you type at the command prompt

```
C:>python --version
```

you should see python version with anaconda version like this:

```
"Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda 4.5.9".
```

When I type `C:>python --version`, all I see is

> "Python 3.6.4"

When I type `C:>conda --version` I see:

> "conda 4.5.9"

I can launch Jupyter Notebook from the command prompt, so I am pretty sure the path is correct.

Is this indicating an issue with path setup?

Comment: What does `echo %PATH%` give?

Comment: It gave my path list. Everything there looks correct. As part of an exercise in our textbook, I used "conda install ipython-notebook". It did, but asked at the end that it would downgrade python from 3.6.4 to 3.5.5 and Anaconda downgrade to  a lower version. So I accepted this. Python and Anaconda now appear together in the Anaconda prompt, but not in the Command prompt. And to make matters stanger the Command prompt says I am running Python 3.6.4 and the Anaconda prompt says 3.5.5. But all seems to be working other than that.

Comment: It looks like you're on Windows :-(  Type:   `where python`

Comment: I think it's all solved now. The through several "conda update..." commands for anaconda, ipython, and python, it all seems to match now. Except the IDLE shell is running 3.6.4 and everything else is 3.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's all solved now. The through several "conda update..." commands for anaconda, ipython, and python, it all seems to match now. Except the IDLE shell is running 3.6.4 and everything else is 3.6.6. –